# Get days from substract to dates using Moment.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, momentjs

I want to set a countdown for events, so only on the case the event hasn't started, a countdown of the days before the event shows. The dates are stored on the database like this DD-MM-YYYY, so I convert them using Moment.js, but I still don't get the remaining days. Here is my code

```
moment.locale('es');
        var hoy = moment().format("DD-MM-YYYY");
        var finicio = moment("20-01-2015", "DD-MM-YYYY").format("DD-MM-YYYY");
        var ffin = moment("19-01-2015", "DD-MM-YYYY").format("DD-MM-YYYY");
        $(function () {
            if (finicio < hoy) {
                $("#estadoevento").text("EXPIRADO");
            }
            else if (finicio > hoy) {
                $("#estadoevento").text("EN ESPERA");
                var contador = moment(finicio).diff(moment(hoy));
                var espera = moment.duration(contador);
                var restante = espera.asDays();
                $("#contador").text("FALTAN " + restante + " DÍAS");
            }
            else {
                $("#estadoevento").text("EN ESTE MOMENTO");
            }
        });
```

But I don't get the values, I don't know if I have to redeclare my variables, currently the code just shows a message on a span tag if event is expired, incoming or today, and works correctly.

Variable finicio is the one that contains the starting date for the event, so if the event starts on five days, I wan't to get that number, I tried, but it returns a 0 value. I'm using jQuery too.

contador variable is the substract of the two dates, variable espera gets the duration of contador, and finally restante changes into days, but I don't know where my code is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, a couple of things.

### Format returns strings

[`.format()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) outputs a **string**.

So when you do `finicio < hoy` you are comparing which string is greater. This would be fine if the strings were formatted as `YYYY-MM-DD` (largest to smallest) but when they have days first, this will not compare them correctly.

Instead, use [`isBefore`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-before/) `isSame` and `isAfter`. And use them with the actual moment objects:

```
var hoy = moment(); // No .format
var finicio = moment("20-01-2015", "DD-MM-YYYY");
var ffin = moment("19-01-2015", "DD-MM-YYYY");

if( hoy.isAfter(finicio) ){ ... }
```

### Creating a moment from a string

This:

```
var contador = moment(finicio).diff(moment(hoy));
```

is the same as

```
var contador = moment('20-01-2015').diff(moment('20-01-2015'));
```

because finicio and how are strings, not moment objects.

Which means you are creating two moment objects from strings without telling moment how they are formatted. If you run `moment('20-01-2015')` alone, you will get an error.

The code will work if you make `finicio` and `hoy` moment objects instead of strings. Or if you provide formatting strings: `moment(finicio,"DD-MM-YYYY")`.

As before, I recommend just removing the `.format` when you create `hoy`,`finicio` and `ffin` so that you have moment objects to work with.

### Edit: Granularity

The other thing with you can do with `isBefore` `isSame` and `isAfter` is set granularity.

```
moment().isSame('2015-02-06'); // false, because time is different
moment().isSame('2015-02-06', 'day'); // true, because anything smaller than days is ignored
```

Here's the **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/slicedtoad/20s1j3h3/8/)** from the comments fixed with granularity.

Comment: A very important thing I missed, I will rewrite this code and edit post with correction applied, if anything goes wrong I will contact you for help :) thanks

Comment: I still have a small problem, since the code works perfectly for previous and later actions, but when trying to get it working on current date case it doesn't work. Here is a JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/20s1j3h3/

Comment: don't know if I'm using isSame correctly or format is not correct

Comment: sorry I was still trying some things, currently the 2nd condition works fine, the problem is when I use isSame, when finicio is equal to current date, it goes for the 3rd condition of else, when it is supposed to show a message that event is currently happening

Comment: try it running it now, I changed finicio so date is equal as today, but it still goes for the else

Comment: correction made, everything is running fine. I saw granulation on documentation but forgot about it. Thanks a lot, where could I post correct code?

Answer (score 0):

With the help I got here, I post correct code for anyone interested

```
moment.locale('es');//Spanish Language for Moment
        var hoy = moment();//Get client systemd date
        var finicio = moment("08-02-2015", "DD-MM-YYYY");//A date for event start
        var ffin = moment("12-02-2015", "DD-MM-YYYY");//A date for event end
        $(function () {
            if (hoy.isSame(finicio, "day")) {
                $("#estadoevento").text("EN ESTE MOMENTO");
            }//To compare todays date with event start date
            else if (hoy.isBefore(finicio)) {
                $("#estadoevento").text("EN ESPERA");
                var falta = finicio.diff(hoy);
                var duracionfalta = moment.duration(falta);
                var faltante = Math.round(duracionfalta.asDays());
                $("#contador").text("FALTAN " + faltante + " DÍAS");
            }//If event hasn't started yet, this shows the amount of days remaining
            else {
                $("#estadoevento").text("EXPIRADO");
            }//When the event already passed
        });
```